# Animate table view cells including header

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I animate the cells of my table view with:

```
func animateCells(tableView: UITableView) {
    tableView.reloadData()

    let cells = tableView.visibleCells
    let tableHeight: CGFloat = tableView.bounds.size.height

    for i in cells {
        let cell: UITableViewCell = i as UITableViewCell
        cell.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeTranslation(0, tableHeight)
    }

    var index = 0

    for a in cells {
        let cell: UITableViewCell = a as UITableViewCell
        UIView.animateWithDuration(animationDuration, delay: animationDelay * Double(index),usingSpringWithDamping: 0.8, initialSpringVelocity: 0, options: [], animations: {
            cell.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeTranslation(0, 0);
            }, completion: nil)

        index += 1
    }
}
```

This works perfectly with only cells in the table view. But I also have some tables with a header, in these cases the animation is not working. How can I include the headers in the animation code above? Thank you.

Comment: I think you have to use `tableView.headerViewForSection()` or `tableView.tableHeaderView` instead of `visibleCells` to get header view.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Solved issue for tableView section header animation:

```
// animate section header
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, willDisplayHeaderView view: UIView, forSection section: Int) {
    let numberOfSections = tableView.numberOfSections
    let tableHeight: CGFloat = tableView.bounds.size.height
    var index = 0

    for i in 0...numberOfSections - 1 {
        if (section == i) {
            view.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeTranslation(0, tableHeight)
            UIView.animateWithDuration(1.0, delay: 0.05 * Double(index),usingSpringWithDamping: 0.8, initialSpringVelocity: 0, options: [], animations: { () -> Void in
                view.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeTranslation(0, 0)
                }, completion: nil)
        }
        index += 1
    }
}
```

and for the cells:

```
// animate cells
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, willDisplayCell cell: UITableViewCell, forRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
    let numberOfSections = tableView.numberOfSections
    let tableHeight: CGFloat = tableView.bounds.size.height
    var index = 0

    for i in 0...numberOfSections - 1 {
        let numberOfCells = tableView.numberOfRowsInSection(i)

        for j in 0...numberOfCells - 1 {
            if (indexPath.section == i && indexPath.row == j) {
                cell.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeTranslation(0, tableHeight)
                UIView.animateWithDuration(1.0, delay: 0.05 * Double(index),usingSpringWithDamping: 0.8, initialSpringVelocity: 0, options: [], animations: {
                    cell.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeTranslation(0, 0);
                    }, completion: nil)
            }
            index += 1
        }
    }
}
```

Thank you for your hints!!

Answer (score 2):

There are two header views in `UITableView`.

### Header view of UITableView

This is an accessory view that is displayed above `UITableView`. It can be set like this:

```
self.tableView.tableHeaderView = UIView()
```

You can get the header view from `tableHeaderView` property as well.

### Header view of sections

Each section can have header view for itself. In order to set the header view of sections `tableView(_:viewForHeaderInSection:)` of `UITableViewDelegate` has to be implemented.

You can get the header view of sections from `headerViewForSection(_:)` of `UITableView`.

```
let headerView = self.tableView.headerViewForSection(0)!
```

The method, `tableView(_:viewForHeaderInSection:)`,  returns `UIView` according to [the reference document](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITableViewDelegate_Protocol/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/UITableViewDelegate/tableView:viewForHeaderInSection:), but it has to return `UITableViewHeaderFooterView` object in your implementation. If `UIView` is returned, `headerViewForSection(_:)` will return `nil`.

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, viewForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> UIView? {
    let headerView = UITableViewHeaderFooterView()
    headerView.backgroundColor = UIColor.redColor()

    return headerView
}
```

I hope to solve your problem with this.

Comment: With `tableView.visibleCells` I can access all the cells of a table view. Is there a similar way to access all sections / section headers of the table view?

Comment: [`headerViewForSection(_:)`](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITableView_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UITableView/headerViewForSection:) seems to be what you want.

Comment: this is to access one section at index XY..but how can i access all sections of my tableView..similar to tableView.visibleCells?

Comment: If you want to access all section headers, use for-loop.

    for i in 0...((self.tableView?.numberOfSections)! - 1) {
        let headerView = self.tableView?.headerViewForSection(i)
        // ...
    }

Comment: I don't know another way to do for that.